# Explicitly assign or access values to or from specific address/location in memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory

My exact question is that there is any provision in `c` and `c++` to assign a value explicitly to particular address for example suppose I want to store `20` at `0x1846010` address in memory and I also want to access a value using this same address (`0x1846010`).

Might be its easy but I am really confused how to do this if we can.

Anyone can explain is that possible, if yes then how (with suitable example) and if not then why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "c\c++"?  C and C++ are two different, but closely related, languages.  The answer to your question *happens* to be the same for both; that's not the case for all possible questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
*(int *)0x1846010 = 20;  // store int value 20 at address 0x1846010
```

Retrieving works similar:

```
int x = *(int *)0x1846010;
```

***Note that this assumes that address 0x1846010 is writable - in most cases this will generate an exception like `Access violation writing location 0x01846010`.***

P.S. For your interest, you can check given address writable or not at run-time by using the following (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433468/how-can-i-check-whether-a-memory-address-is-writable-or-not-at-runtime/14437277#14437277)):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int is_writeable(void *p)
{
    int fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
    int writeable;

    if (fd < 0)
        return -1; /* Should not happen */

    writeable = read(fd, p, 1) == 1;
    close(fd);

    return writeable;
}
```

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661190/2589776), typically you will only ever do this kind of thing for embedded code etc where there is no OS and you need to write to specific memory locations such as registers, I/O ports or special types of memory (e.g. `NVRAM`).

Comment: Note that "exception" is also a technical term in C++ that's unrelated to the way you use it.

Comment: @VikasVerma This is usually supposed to happen, i.e. when it's not writable.

Comment: There is any way to know that particular address is valid or not ?

Comment: @VikasVerma For Unix OS, you can do it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14437277/2589776). Answer also updated.

Comment: @VikasVerma Not valid for 0 and -1.

Comment: @VikasVerma: If you don't already know the address is valid, and you can't define for us what "valid" means in this context, then why are you attempting to do this?

Comment: Actually I was just doing some small experiments

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I already mentioned this at the end of my answer. Updated the answer to make more clear though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Assuming that `0x1846010` is a valid address to which you have write access, you can write:

```
*(int*)0x1846010 = 20;
```

And to access the stored value:

```
printf("%d\n", *(int*)0x1846010);
```

And if you actually do that in a program, it will probably crash, because `0x1846010` very probably *isn't* a valid address to which you have write access.

Why exactly do you want to do this? How do you know (if you know) that `0x1846010` is a valid address?

This assumes that the conversion of the integer value `0x1846010` to a pointer is even meaningful. The result of the conversion is *implementation-defined*, but is "intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment".

Comment: There is any way to know that particular address is valid or not ?

Comment: @VikasVerma: Maybe. That's entirely system-specific. Why do you care? Where did the number `0x1846010` come from? If storing the value `20` at address `0x1846010` is the solution to your problem, *what is that problem*?

Comment: I was just see the address of any particular variable using & operator like cout<< &a ;. Actually I am new to c++ and just doing some experiments so this question just striked in my mind and when I couldn't do this then I asked here .

Comment: @VikasVerma: So you know that `0x1846010` is the address of some variable in your program (you should have mentioned that). At least, it was the address *on that particular run of your program*; there's no guarantee that it will have the same address the next time you run it. If you have a variable name, just use the name; there is simply no good reason to use its raw address like that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the platform and OS (if any) you are using. The herohuyongtao's solution is usually valid BY THE LANGUAGE'S POINT OF VIEW. The real problem is the meaning of addresses in your environment (in other words: what is your goal exactly?). If you are using a modern OS, addresses are almost surely virtual (i.e. translated in a transparent way by the CPU's memory management unit). If your goal is to write on some specific PHYSICAL cell (i.e. because it hosts a device and you want to drive it), you must first be sure that the OS has created a view on the physical address for you. The way to do it depends completely on the OS's API. Even if you don't ave any OS, it's nevertheless possible that the addresses you are handling are not "physical". It depends on the CPU and the way it's initialized.
A completely different case is when your goal is to change a particular address because "you know" that in your environment it has a specific meaning. I.e. an OS may store at a known virtual address some useful information. Many OSs are used to store at a fixed address a copy of the environment variables and command line arguments, so the C runtime library can easily find them. If this is your case, the herohuyongtao's suggestion is usually good.