# Allocating object to predefined address in c++ without placement new method

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor, placement-new

Is it possible in c++ to allocate an object at a specific place in memory? I'm implementing my hobby os kernel memory manager which gives `void*` addresses to store my stuff and I would like to know how can I use that pointer to allocate my object there. I have tried this:

```
string* s = (string*)235987532//Whatever address is given.
*s = string("Hello from string\n\0");//My own string class
//This seems to call the strings destructor here even thought I am using methods from s after this in my code...
```

The only problem with this is that it calls string objects destructor which it shouldn't do. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I cannot use placement new because I'm developing in kernel level.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C`?

Comment: @legends2k: now it's not.  :)

Comment: `I cannot use placement new because I'm developing in kernel level.` Eh?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288582/can-we-do-assign-or-access-a-value-explicitly-to-or-from-specific-address-locati

Comment: You've created a temporary `string`, its destructor _should_ be called. Why do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: You should really explain *why* you cannot use placement `new` - it's *the* feature designed for this exact use.

Comment: @Angew That's because I'm developing my own kernel.

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer How is that preventing you?

Comment: @Angew Because I the only libraries I can use right now are stdint and stddef. I can't even use new method because I currently have only stack available and I'm trying to implement the new method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to first implement the `operator new` used by placement new:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept
{
  return ptr;
}
```

(See `[new.delete.placement]` in C++11)

Then, you can use placement new the way it's intended to.

Answer (score 5):

Assignment only works if there's a valid object there already. To create an object at an arbitrary memory location, use placement new:

```
new (s) string("Hello");
```

Once you've finished with it, you should destroy it with an explicit destructor call

```
s->~string();
```

**UPDATE:** I just noticed that your question stipulates "without placement new". In that case, the answer is "you can't".

Comment: Didnt even know that it is possible to call the destructor explicitily :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use placement new.  There is not an alternative, because this is precisely what placement new is for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use placement new allocation

```
void* memory = malloc(sizeof(string));
string* myString = new (memory) string();
```

source: [What is an in-place constructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763846/what-is-an-in-place-constructor-in-c)

Comment: But bizarrely the OP stipulated "without placement new."

Comment: `malloc` is likely an over-simplification of requirements here. Either he needs a more hand-crafted memory allocation method, or none at all.

Comment: @John he edited it after I post, now what Mike said applies, you cant(what he does is Undefined Behvaiour); Lightness yes, I just "copied" the solution from the link